# JQuery list append item not selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, append

I have a weird issue with a jquery append to a list.

```
<ul id="idNicheItems" class="clScrollItems ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <li id="NicheItem_1"> Item 1</li>
    <li id="NicheItem_2"> Item 2</li>
    <li id="NicheItem_3"> Item 3</li>
    <li id="NicheItem_4"> Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

The list is part of a list box type control using

```
 $("#idNicheItems li").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("clListHighlight");
      },function(){$(this).removeClass("clListHighlight");});
```

This all works fine.

After a json query later on I append a new item to the list . When I inspect it using firebug it looks just like every other item in the list - ids are unique - everything looks fine.

The trouble is that I can not highlight it or select it.

My thoughts are that I have to call the above `"$("#idNicheItems li")`. hover ..again to attach the hover function after inserting the node - but that does not seem to work - unless I have a bug in my bug fix.

Am I on the right track?

**Answered Own Question** - But my rep is lower than an earthworms belly button - but it may be of use to someone else so wont delete it.

Looks like I had a bug in my bug fix or a dirty cache - that of course fixed itself 20 seconds after posting....

Anyway **lesson for the day**. After inserting a new item using jQuery append prepend etc to an existing list or collection of items that have behavior associated with them - do not forget to attach the behavior to the new item.

In other words call whatever selector code you called on the original items for the new items.

Comment: Instead of `$("#idNicheItems li").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("clListHighlight");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("clListHighlight");
});`, you can simply do `$("#idNicheItems li").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("clListHighlight");
});`. Same effect with less code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user live(),It's binding to the root node of the DOM tree rather than an element:

```
$("#idNicheItems li").live('mouseover',function(){$(this).addClass("clListHighlight")});
$("#idNicheItems li").live('mouseout',function(){$(this).removeClass("clListHighlight")});
```

Comment: `live()` is so deprecated. Use `on()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue is that `$("#idNicheItems li").hover(..)` will bind the mouseover and out handlers *only to those elements that are existing in the DOM tree at the time of calling .hover()*.

You can solve this by using `.on()` like:

```
$("#idNicheItems")
    .on('mouseover', 'li', function() {
        $(this).addClass("clListHighlight");
    })
    .on('mouseout', 'li', function() {
        $(this).removeClass("clListHighlight");
    });
```